# Hackerrank Python Hash Tables: Ransom Note - Terminated due to timeout :(

Tags: python, hashtable

Encoutering "Terminated due to timeout" Error for Hackerrank Hash Table: Ransom Note for 6 out of 21 test cases

Implemented open address hashing. The size of input strings is up to 30,000 strings: Have experimented with changing the hash table size from 60,000 to 300,000 to no success.

```
CAPACITY = 300000
hashTable = [None] * CAPACITY

def checkMagazine(magazine, note):
    # Store Magazine into hashtable
    for element in magazine:
        # print("STORED " + element)
        position = calculateHash(element)
        # print(position)
        if hashTable[position] == None:
            hashTable[position] = element
            # print("Stored into " + str(position))
        else:
            i = 1
            # print("collided into " + str((position) % CAPACITY))
            while hashTable[(position + i) % CAPACITY] != None:
                # print("collided into " + str((position + i) % CAPACITY))
                i += 1
            hashTable[(position + i) % CAPACITY] = element


    # Check if all items in note is in hashtable
    included = True
    for item in note:
        position = calculateHash(item)
        if hashTable[position] != item:
            i = 1
            while hashTable[(position + i ) % CAPACITY] != item:
                if hashTable[(position + i ) % CAPACITY] == None:
                    included = False
                    print("No")
                    return
                else:
                    i += 1
            hashTable[(position + i ) % CAPACITY] = "DONED"
        else:
            hashTable[position] = "DONED"
        # print("Found " + item)            


    print("Yes") 

def calculateHash(string):
    return hash(string) % CAPACITY
```

Given that hash table is the optimal way to solve this problem (time complexity O(n)), is the reason why the timeout is happening is because of open address hashing? Or is there another reason?

Comment: Are you referring to this [HackerRank question](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/ctci-ransom-note/problem)? If so there are much less complicated ways to solve it.

Comment: Echoing the above, it's not clear if you are trying to implement a hash table in a python list as a learning exercise for yourself or not? If not, you should be aware you can use a python set in a similar way with *significantly* less code.

Comment: Incidentally, if you *are* implementing a hash table for your own learning, I'd strongly suggest you also encapsulate it in it's own class which will help oyu think about the interface it needs to provide.

Comment: For what it's worth, I solved this problem without hashing or sorting and passed all tests without timing out.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue relates to your implementation. Have a look at what happens to your code if you pass a large "magazine" input like `["a", "a", "a", .... "a"]`.

Comment: Note I'm assuming you're doing this self-implementation of a has for personal/learning reasons, and as such I'm trying to avoid spoon feeding you the exact answer, but happy to do so if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Should have tried something like this:

```
magazine = 'two times three is not four'
note = 'two times two is four'

if set(magazine.split()) & set(note.split()) == set(note.split()) :
    print 'yes'
else :
    print 'no'
```

you may save some time by precalculating `set(note.split())`, but I doubt it's very large.

if you care about the number of words, you may use `Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter
```

and then check for every word in the note the counter is smaller than the counter for the same word in magazine.